# Confused by result of MoonPosition when running on Linux

Tags: curated-data, linux, astronomy

I've just switched from Windows to Linux and am running Mathematica 10.1 on Ubuntu 14.04.

```
MoonPosition[]
```

Gives me:

> ```
> {QuantityUnits`Private`ToQuantity[
>    QuantityUnits`Private`UnknownQuantity[68.77, "AngularDegrees"]], 
>  QuantityUnits`Private`ToQuantity[
>    QuantityUnits`Private`UnknownQuantity[-41.62, "AngularDegrees"]]}
> ```

I was expecting something more like:

> ```
> {Quantity[280.60, "AngularDegrees"], Quantity[16.95, "AngularDegrees"]}
> ```

Any idea what might be going on here?

Comment: From Mathematica 10.2 on Ubuntu, I am getting{Quantity[211.56, "AngularDegrees"], Quantity[37.54, "AngularDegrees"]} which seems ok for UK.

Comment: Thanks demm. It's the structure of the answer that concerns me, not the actual values. But you're getting the documented structure, so it's good to know that somebody on Ubuntu is.

Comment: `{Quantity[9.38, "AngularDegrees"], Quantity[-38.44, "AngularDegrees"]}` - works as advertised with Mathematica 10.0.2 on Xubuntu 15.04.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, as the OP themselves notes in their answer, the problem was not reproducible after restarting *Mathematica*. Since it is impossible to know what actually caused this, the question is too localized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was more pervasive than just MoonPosition as I noticed the same sort of odd result from DateDifference. Anyway, I restarted the kernel and everything started working as expected. Still have no idea what I did to get it into the strange state in the first place, but at least it's better now.